# want to get the oracle product link which ensures oracle 11.2.0.2 is compatible with AIX 7.1?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

is Oracle client 11.2.0.2 is compatible with AIX 7.1? if so help me with the vendor link which ensures it is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I looked it up for you in Oracle Support site: "**Oracle Database 11.2.0.2.0 is certified on IBM AIX on POWER Systems (64-bit) 7.1**"

For details, have a look at Doc ID 1307544.1 in Oracle Support site.

32-bit version is not though.